# Hide .svn folders in a VS2010 IronPython project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I'm working on an IronPython project on VS2010 and I've notice that for the python project (which is setup as a Console project, but really just contains a number of scripts that are hosted in a C# app), everything that is in the project directory will show up in the VS solution explorer under that project.  So, for example, the .svn folder shows up.  Which I obviously don't want or need to be there.

Is there any way to tell it to hide specific items? I sure can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we have a directory based project system - which as you have seen includes all of the files in the project dir.  We were planning on having an exclude option but the feedback we've been hearing so far is that we should move to a normal VS project model where you need to explicitly add the files.  The next CTP release (which should be out in a week or so) will change to a normal project model.

There does still seem to be some interest in the directory based model so we may bring it back via an option in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just right click the folder, choose "Exclude from Project"

Then, make sure "Show all files" is NOT on at the top, by the solution.

Comment: yeah, other project types have that option, but not IronPython